# Linearlayout like a "ListView" containing objects in android?

Tags: android-layout, android-listview, android-linearlayout, android

I am making a list using `LinearLayout` and would like to add several "person"-objects to my "list" 
I need to be able to click on an object in this list an pull out the person object or at least the personId to be able to find the specific person in my database.

How do I go about doing this? 
I have tried using a `TextView` but it is too simple to contain all of the desired values.

I have also tried using a `ListView` but I have several `LinearLayout` next to each other. The `ListView` scroll individually and therefore I can't use them

Here is an image:
[image: Each column is a linearView and each row is supposed to be an object]

As you can see I am trying to make a grid of sorts each column is a linearview and at the moment so are each row.
I realize there is a grid but I need to be able to fit objects in where I want them and I am too inexperienced to write my own adapter for the gridview

Comment: then use ListView with customized row layout ...

Comment: I can't use listview because I have made a grid of linearlayouts and the listview uses the scrollbar when it gets too big

Comment: what is the problem with using listview ?? your all problem can be easily fixed by using listview.

Comment: I could use a listview if I was able to disable scrolling and make it expand according to the items it contains

Comment: You need to provide a drawing of the design you are trying to achieve or a better description

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `ListView` with a custom `ArrayAdapter`.

Check out this [example](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429).

Instead of the `Weather` class, use your own `Person` object and make the necessary modifications.

**Edit:**

After reading your edit, I can see that you have some kind of Grid. So my best guess would be to use a `GridView` with a custom adapter.
Since you are getting your data from a database, you might as well use a custom `CursorAdapter`.

But I still haven't figured out what you're trying to do.

It seems that you want all the cells to be visible. That would only mean you have a small/finite amount of cells, and in that case a GridView wouldn't be any better than a for loop that adds views to a layout.

Comment: That seems like a good solution if I could only disable scrolling and make the listview expand according to the items in it

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to do? If your items don't fit the screen, you're obviously going to have to scroll down.